# ansible expect module not working with openshift installer

Tags: ansible, openshift

I have created an ansible task to generate openshift config from openshift installer. When done manually, install config gets generated successfully. It asks for user input like shown below:

```
? SSH Public Key  [Use arrows to move, type to filter, ? for more help]
  /home/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  /home/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa_os.pub
> <none>
? Platform  [Use arrows to move, type to filter, ? for more help]
> aws
  azure
? Region  [Use arrows to move, type to filter, ? for more help]
  eu-west-2 (London)
> eu-west-3 (Paris)
? Base Domain [? for help]
? Cluster Name [? for help]
? Pull Secret [? for help]
```

I have created ansible task for same as shown above:

```
- name: openshift install config
  expect:
    command: ./openshift-install create install-config --dir={{ install_dir }}
    responses:
      SSH Public Key : "{{ public_key }}"
      Platform : aws
      Region : "{{ AWS_REGION }}"
      Base Domain : xxxxxxxx.com
      Cluster Name : xxxxxx-cluster
      Pull Secret : xxxxxxxxxx
```

It err with "msg": "command exceeded timeout". Increasing timeout to higher value than default 30 sec doesn't help.

Comment: You timeout because the script is still waiting for ever for a response. Either your `responses` don't match correctly, or there is a difference when running the script manually and through ansible. If your are positively sure of the order of questions, you can give the answers as a simple list of strings in the correct order since ansible 2.1 (see [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html)). Try it. If it works, there is a problem with your current matches. If it doesn't then your script is asking for something else when launched from ansible.

Comment: The better way to do this would be to create the install-config.yaml file manually or via an ansible template and feed _that_ into ```openshift-install create ignition```